# "Test Integrity" in Archive manager on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: file-roller

I recently updated to 13.10 (fresh install) and I noticed Archive Manager does not provide a "Test Integrity" option for compressed files anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, never mind. There is a small arrow at the far right of the toolbar, and the test integrity option is there now.

I wish it could be integrated (or better, I wish I knew how to integrate it) into the regular application menu, and as shortcut in **Files** right-click menu.